# How to get Deleted By in Sharepoint

Tags: web-services

I have created a list "Modification Log".Then a workflow for ADD and  EDIT.How Can I get "Deleted By" like "Created By" and "Modified By".Please help to have a solution for delete also.
This is my code

private void onWorkflowActivated1_Invoked(object sender, ExternalDataEventArgs e)
        {

```
        SPWeb oSPWeb = workflowProperties.Web;

        oSPWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;

        SPList oSPList = oSPWeb.Lists["Modification Log"];

        SPListItem oSPListItem = workflowProperties.Item;

        SPListItem oSPListItm = oSPList.Items.Add();

        oSPListItm["Project Code"] = oSPListItem["Project Code"];

        oSPListItm["Project Details"] = oSPListItem["Project Details"];

        oSPListItm["Resource Name"] = oSPListItem["Resource Name"];

        oSPListItm["Department"] = oSPListItem["Department"]; 

        if (Convert.ToString(oSPListItem["Modified By"]) != string.Empty)

        {
            oSPListItm["Operation Done By"] = oSPListItem["Created By"];

            oSPListItm["Operation"] = "ADD";
        }

        else

        {
            oSPListItm["Operation Done By"] = oSPListItem["Modified By"];

            oSPListItm["Operation"] = "EDIT";
        }

        oSPListItm.Update();

        oSPWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

If you really want to get a log of all events in the list you should look on the audit capabilities in SharePoint. There's a ready infrastructure for it but you have to write code to enable it and to view the reports. See the details [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397403%28v=office.12%29.aspx). It's about MOSS 2007 but it works identically in all the editions of SharePoint 2007 and 2010. It allows to view the delete events among many others.

Comment: I would add that while the reports and user interface for setting auditing up are not very good, the API is fairly well built.